# how to change swiper attribute when meet a condition

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

so i have like 4 slides, on slide 2 i add a class `.no-next` so after i slide from slide 1 to slide 2, i cant go to slide 3.

this is the setting i use

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        pagination: {
          el: '.swiper-pagination',
          clickable: true,          
        },
        direction: 'horizontal',
        slidesPerView: 1,
        spaceBetween: 1,
        mousewheel: true, // i intend to change this
        lazy: true,
        speed: 700,
        // grabCursor: true,
        parallax: true,
        keyboard: {
          enabled: true,
        },
    });
  swiper.on('slideChange', function () {
      if($(swiper-slide).hasClass('no-next')){
       mousewheel: false,
      }else{
        mousewheel: true,
      }
  });
```

how to set the mousewheel to false after i slide to slide 2. thank you